# gem install memcached fails on osx

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, memcached, rbenv

I'm unable to get gem to install memcached on osx (Mavricks). I have installed memcached and libmemcache with brew.

```
gem install memcached -v '1.0.6'
```

I've put the output [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/thesmith/8022517) as there's a lot of it. I'm using rbenv with ruby 1.9.3p484. I've done a lot of googling but haven't found a similar failure. Let me know if you need more data.

Comment: it seems that linker did not find for the `libs` of the ruby core...

Comment: Any idea how to tell it where to look?

Comment: FYI 1.7.2 installs cleanly.

Comment: it need to investigate try to run for beginning `ldconfig` in console

Comment: I actually found the answer to this. You need to make sure you compile Ruby with the --enable-shared flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The --enabled-shared flag fixed it in the end. Here was the whole line I used to re-install ruby:

```
CC=/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2 CONFIGURE_OPTS="-C --enable-shared --with-readline-dir=$(brew --prefix readline) --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/gdbm:/usr/local/opt/libffi --without-tcl --without-tk CC=/usr/local/opt/apple-gcc42/bin/gcc-4.2" rbenv install 1.9.3-p484
```